# beautifulsoup get_text() function not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, gettext

so, i was making a covid map using web scraping, but i have never used it, anyways here is my python code

```
    import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://news.google.com/covid19/map?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen&mid=%2Fm%2F016zwt')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
week = soup.find_all(class_='l3HOY')
print(week[7]).get_text()
```

but when i try to run it, it gives this error

```
  print(week[7].find('td').get_text())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

can anyone tell me how i can fix it?

Comment: This means beautifulsoup extraction failed

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://news.google.com/covid19/map?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen&mid=%2Fm%2F016zwt')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
week = soup.select(".l3HOY")
print(week[7].get_text())
```

Output:
15,964

Changes you have to make

1. `get_text` method is on the `week` element not on the print statement
2. If you want all the elements with a particular class, then better go with css selector